# 404 when POST-ing with Acute characters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis

My feedback controller replies with 404 Not Found when I POST to it, with a JQuery AJAX with form data, when any of the fields contains an acute character (áíóú), but works fine when it doesn't. I've checked the headers of both requests and the only differences are the length and the acute characters themselves.

I've tried to find the issue but I can't seem to figure it out.

Should I perform some sort of encoding on top of the URL encode that JQuery does automatically?

EDIT:

This is my controller Post method:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public JsonResult Post(FeedbackViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

This is my FeedbackViewModel:

```
public class FeedbackViewModel
{
    //Llenado por MVC
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //Llenado por Javascript
    public string Environment { get; set; }

    //Llenado por Usuario
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(254)]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public static FeedbackViewModel Create(AppContext appContext)
    {
        return new FeedbackViewModel
        {
            Name = appContext.CurrentUser.FullName,
            Email = appContext.CurrentUser.Email
        };
    }
}
```

And my JavaScript

```
dialog = BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: "Feedback",
    message: "Connecting to Visum...",
    type: "type-default",
    closable : true,
    onshow: function (dialog) {
        dialog.enableButtons(false);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Feedback"
        }).always(processData).fail(function(data) {
            dialog.setType(BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER);
            dialog.setMessage("An unexpected error occured");
        }).success(function(data) {

        });
    },
    buttons: [
        {
            icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-send",
            label: "Submit",
            cssClass: "btn-primary",
            id: "btn-send",
            action: function (dialog) {
                var summary = dialog.getModalBody().find("#title").val();
                var description = dialog.getModalBody().find('#desc').val();
                if ($.trim(summary).length == 0) {
                    alert(dialog.data.summaryValidate);
                    return false;
                } else if ($.trim(description).length == 0) {
                    alert(dialog.data.commentValidate);
                    return false;
                }
                dialog.enableButtons(false);
                dialog.setClosable(false);

                dialog.data.data.Description= description;
                dialog.data.data.Summary= summary;
                dialog.data.data.Image= image_data;
                dialog.data.data.Environment=
                        "Location: " + window.location.href + "; \n" +
                        "Refferer: " + document.referrer + "; \n" +
                        "Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "; \n" +
                        "Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "; \n" +
                        "Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "; \n" +
                        "Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "; \n" +
                        "Browser Language: " + navigator.language + "; \n" +
                        "Browser Online: " + navigator.onLine + "; \n" +
                        "Platform: " + navigator.platform + "; \n" +
                        "User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "; \n";

                $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: dialog.data.postUrl, data: dialog.data.data,  }).always(function data() {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        dialog.close();
                    }, 5000);
                }).success(function (data) {
                    dialog.setType(BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS);
                    dialog.setMessage("Feedback sent, this dialog will close in 5 seconds");

                }).fail(function (data) {
                    dialog.setType(BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER);
                    dialog.setMessage("An unexpected error occured, this dialog will close in 5 seconds");

                });

            }
        }
    ]
});
```

A request made without acute characters:

```
Remote Address:191.238.240.12:80
Request URL:http://visumdevelop.azurewebsites.net/Feedback/Post
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:es
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:657
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:__RequestVerificationToken=cQ3i-o1oc-FCG6E-jH4zGvvT_jZDiCTc6T3sxsiCoev0bTbS1qZQs6pELHXlnwQl6Kb9tQZD2OSXPfrvuTSHwpPCUb2jbdlqdv4Cd-    ojkLY1; ASP.NET_SessionId=gy2xgbolalfi350qzdrhv3ti; ARRAffinity=ba9e0a23e4392153bdbbc0e711ccce8c551bdcf826855839d26c9823bcd080e3; .AspNet.    ApplicationCookie=WMaJFzn_RUEKlddRBi4_rg83_UcGDJvnk-vhjtPnvUqeN8If_3DIS3jQeqCBLeVB_mYR6HT4_AicuY-    HlrNdNDPLvgPTOacCk2vZTZQNRbtUn7Wk4C1rCTR45K27FyRdzqXB4xqilzt5vQiBG1ppexLR-C-entHfCoSaEtqPw2h3jxgEZsrnyT-HTUt-ZLxfJ0AOO_qN31xZnOfG2tV77Z-    sl7rPUXE_ZHCHPPGMZ51IMqi2CyiJArKpKtFqplnHVuNLMhM-93j9WeXVnU5Wsc29DgB_8P2aJPQ89mN95tJN8I8ZmXi4JnkQIVpEqPn0mkk_2o466fTtibZ0C0hnDx1DVd98ZNOIM-    Qoxm476LUCGIel4-kX7lgmA2BoJQHR4KD8f9fBjiF3xdOjdHJjw6bU_0JVKURo6S3yipHAxPm-    PZtkmcj6QMtlWsrp8rvBnUJF5qDUpi_sX9bODzxv8rZg0S2XErCzgdGx02vilDOhp6j8_FdMosheLoEFACyR
DNT:1
Host:visumdevelop.azurewebsites.net
Origin:http://visumdevelop.azurewebsites.net
Referer:http://visumdevelop.azurewebsites.net/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
Name:Adminsitrador de Visum
Email:visumadmin@incostas.com
Environment:Location: http://visumdevelop.azurewebsites.net/; 
Refferer: ; 
Browser CodeName: Mozilla; 
Browser Name: Netscape; 
Browser Version: 5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36; 
Cookies Enabled: true; 
Browser Language: en-us; 
Browser Online: true; 
Platform: Win32; 
User-agent header: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36; 
Summary:TEST
Description:TEST aiou
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:212
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 09 Mar 2015 21:29:11 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.0 localhost (squid)
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:5.2
X-Cache:MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup:MISS from localhost:3128
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

A request made with acute characters:

```
Remote Address:191.238.240.12:80
Request URL:http://visumdevelop.azurewebsites.net/Feedback/Post
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:es
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:677
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:__RequestVerificationToken=cQ3i-o1oc-FCG6E-jH4zGvvT_jZDiCTc6T3sxsiCoev0bTbS1qZQs6pELHXlnwQl6Kb9tQZD2OSXPfrvuTSHwpPCUb2jbdlqdv4Cd-    ojkLY1; ASP.NET_SessionId=gy2xgbolalfi350qzdrhv3ti; ARRAffinity=ba9e0a23e4392153bdbbc0e711ccce8c551bdcf826855839d26c9823bcd080e3; .AspNet.    ApplicationCookie=WMaJFzn_RUEKlddRBi4_rg83_UcGDJvnk-vhjtPnvUqeN8If_3DIS3jQeqCBLeVB_mYR6HT4_AicuY-    HlrNdNDPLvgPTOacCk2vZTZQNRbtUn7Wk4C1rCTR45K27FyRdzqXB4xqilzt5vQiBG1ppexLR-C-entHfCoSaEtqPw2h3jxgEZsrnyT-HTUt-ZLxfJ0AOO_qN31xZnOfG2tV77Z-    sl7rPUXE_ZHCHPPGMZ51IMqi2CyiJArKpKtFqplnHVuNLMhM-93j9WeXVnU5Wsc29DgB_8P2aJPQ89mN95tJN8I8ZmXi4JnkQIVpEqPn0mkk_2o466fTtibZ0C0hnDx1DVd98ZNOIM-    Qoxm476LUCGIel4-kX7lgmA2BoJQHR4KD8f9fBjiF3xdOjdHJjw6bU_0JVKURo6S3yipHAxPm-    PZtkmcj6QMtlWsrp8rvBnUJF5qDUpi_sX9bODzxv8rZg0S2XErCzgdGx02vilDOhp6j8_FdMosheLoEFACyR
DNT:1
Host:visumdevelop.azurewebsites.net
Origin:http://visumdevelop.azurewebsites.net
Referer:http://visumdevelop.azurewebsites.net/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
Name:Adminsitrador de Visum
Email:visumadmin@incostas.com
Environment:Location: http://visumdevelop.azurewebsites.net/; 
Refferer: ; 
Browser CodeName: Mozilla; 
Browser Name: Netscape; 
Browser Version: 5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36; 
Cookies Enabled: true; 
Browser Language: en-us; 
Browser Online: true; 
Platform: Win32; 
User-agent header: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36; 
Summary:TEST
Description:TEST áíóú
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:103
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 09 Mar 2015 21:30:58 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Via:1.0 localhost (squid)
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:5.2
X-Cache:MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup:MISS from localhost:3128
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: Post your controller signature and your javascript here so we can see if anything jumps out as out of the ordinary. And your HTTP headers and post body might be helpful as well.

Comment: That all looks normal enough to me. One thing I might suggest would be to try to post as JSON instead of as form-encoded - I don't see how that could be the problem, but it's worth a shot. You'd have to set `contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8"` and do `data: JSON.stringify(dialog.data.data)`, but nothing else should need to change.

Comment: I changed the script to send the data as a json object and the same thing happens. It accepts and processes the request correctly, but 404's when it contains characters such as áíóúñ

Answer (score 1):

Jira API requires content with UTF-8 characters to have the correct header.

However the issue was not related in any way to my program. It was actually caused by a firewall malforming the request (stripping the utf-8 encoding header) that is made against the Jira API which is behind said firewall.

Comment: Ouch. Always tough when it's something you have no control over. You might be able to get around that by using unicode literals with JSON, so `\u00E1` instead of `á`. I don't know how you could do that across the board though.